# Key Error 4 in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I keep getting this error whenever I delete part of a dictionary in python. 
Early on I have

```
del the_dict[1]
```

and then later when I run through the dictionary I immediately get the error

```
test_self = the_dict[element_x]
```

KeyError: 4

Does anyone have any idea what that error is. Everything is properly deleted from the dictionary, but when I go back to search through it, I get this error.

Comment: Show a minimal but complete program that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Note that `KeyError: 4` doesn't mean error number 4, but rather that you're looking for a key in the dictionary with value `4`, and it doesn't exist. Does this help explain the message?

Comment: Elements in dictionary are not accessed on index, but on key. Is value `1` your key,  or, you are using it as index.?

Comment: If you want to be sure that the key `element_x` (which is 4 in your case) does NOT exist in your dictionary, do `element_x in the_dict` and it should return `False`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that you are by mistake trying to access the dictionary element on index. You can't do that. You need to access dict value on key. As dictionary is not ordered.

E.g :-

```
>>> my_dict = {1:2, 3:4}
>>> my_dict
{1: 2, 3: 4}
>>> 
>>> del my_dict[0]  # try to delete `key: 1`

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    del my_dict[0]
KeyError: 0
>>> del my_dict[1]  # Access by key value.
>>> my_dict   # dict after deleting key 
{3: 4}
>>> my_dict[1]   # Trying to access deleted key.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    my_dict[1]
KeyError: 1
```

> Everything is properly deleted from the dictionary, but when I go back
>   to search through it

You of course cannot get the value of key, that you have deleted. That will give you `KeyError`. Why would you want to do something like that? I mean, why you want to access the thing, which you know does not exist?

Alternatively, you can use `in` operator to check for the existence of a key in your dictionary: -

```
>>> my_dict = {1:2 , 3:4}
>>> 4 in my_dict
False
>>> 1 in my_dict
True
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that I explained it properly. 1-10 are the keys of the dictionary. So the dictionary looks like the_dict = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'....}    So later when I go back through the dictionary and ask what is the_dict[2] I get the error.

Comment: @ben.. Ok, then look at the explanation below the first code. I think you are trying to access a key after deleting it. Which you can't do.

Comment: please my above comment to clarify my original explanation.

Comment: @ben.. Are you doing that check after deleting the key `2`? Check whether the key exist in dictionary using: - `2 in the_dict` and see whether its True.

Comment: You are right. I was calling back through the dictionary with the original set of keys and forgetting to remove the keys as I was deleting them. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @ben.. Ah! I doubted that.And now that you got it. You're welcome :)